# Not able to translate module data in already existing DB in Openerp

Tags: odoo, po

I am having one .po file for Danish / Dansk language. When I use this file in a module and create a new database it is working fine. But when I use the file for already existing database its not working. Can it possible to translate the data into the Danish / Dansk for already existing databases? If yes how it can be acheived?
Is there any need to change in PO file code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the module in which the .po file is located, another alternative is "Load an offical Translation" option under Adminstration and turn on the "Overwrite existing terms"